# Strange error in R.java, even after cleaning the project: "Underscores can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-resources

So everything was going quite nicely, until just a while ago when R.java decided to have this error after adding an icon (`5_content_new.png`, to be exact).

I've tried cleaning the project and restarting eclipse, to no avail.

The problem code:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int 5_content_new=0x7f020000;
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020001;
    ...
}
```

The red line appears right under `5_`, and the error says:

`Underscores can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater`

Has anyone encountered a problem like this before?

Comment: Variable names must start with a non-digit.  A digit indicates a number, and numbers can only have underscores in them in java 1.7 and higher.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a combination of two things:

1. Java identifiers cannot start with a digit.  The first character should be a letter.
2. In Java 7, they introduced alternative syntaxes for integer literals; e.g. `1_000` is the same as `1000`.

So what is happening is that the compiler is parsing `5_content_new` as `5_ content_new` ... which is reasonable if the source level was Java 7, and then telling you that you are not using Java 7.  If you HAD been using Java 7, that compilation error would have been replaced by an error that said that an integer literal (`5_`) was not legal at that point.

In short, the code contains something so "off the wall" that the compiler writer didn't anticipate it in the compiler diagnostic code.

---

The other point is that using ANY underscores in a variable, method, class or package name in Java is a *style violation*.  Underscores should only be used in all-caps constant names like "MAX_VALUE".

Comment: Very informative! R.java is generated when an Android project is built, and lower case + underscores seemed to be the style people used for resources. It's most likely this is done because they're referenced in xml, though I'm no authority on naming conventions :)

Comment: Yea ... well style errors in generated code are unfortunate, but you shouldn't *need* to look at it.  In this case, it looks like whatever generated `R.java` has a bug ...

Comment: Underscores can be used as separators where camel case does not work well.  E.g. Having URL as part of the class name.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - you could do that, but many style guides / style checkers would still call it a style violation.

Answer (score 3):

I just now tried renaming an existing drawable in a compiling-fine Android project of mine and Eclipse threw this dialog up:

[image: Eclipse Error]
(If you can't see the image very well, the dialog box is saying *The resource name must begin with a character.*

The way that I produced this dialog was renaming a drawable file. The drawable's original name was `button_blue_normal.9.png`, renamed it to `5_button_blue_normal.9.png` and pressed enter. Dialog popped up immediately after pressing enter.

I never knew this but apparently you'll need a letter-character, **not a digit**, at the very beginning of a drawable's file name.

Comment: Thank you! That would actually make sense, seeing as (iirc) variable names aren't supposed to start with numbers in java.

Comment: You are simply superb :D :D +1

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but I just ran into this myself when I started working with the ActionBar component.

ScootrNova's answer led me to the solution.  The problem was the Android-recommended icon pack that I downloaded for use in the tutorials.  All the filenames began with integers (1_xxx.png, etc).  I removed the ones I wasn't using, renamed the others to something that began with a letter (I used "icon_xxx.png" as an example), and it compiled without error.

Comment: Yeah, this is the same problem that I had. 5_content_new.png was in the icon pack

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it after putting digit after text not at begining.
I had line **2_Activity** and I changed it to **Activity2**. It was my solution. Hope that it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Resolution: Look at the res files, drawlables or inside xml and rename files or strings that start with (number underscore string) 1_string to string_1.

Hope this helps to resolve the problem.