# R.java gives an error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

My R.java gives an error

> > > > public static final int 1405308882_more = 0x7f020000

Don't know or understand why its giving this error, i regenerate the R.java file and it still gives me the following above. and when i hover my mouse over it, it says

> > > > underscore have to be located within digits

I tried editing it but when it compiles it still regenerate the same name variable.

Please before anyone starts rating this question as usless take your time to understand it
I don't have error in any of my java files either in the src folder or layout folder every thing else is fine its just the R.java that generates that constant so please understand before you jump to conclusions. Thank you.

Comment: Variable (or constant) names cannot start with a digit

Comment: Please refer variable naming conventions - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: @MindPeace i didn't do the naming, this is generated by eclipse in the R.java file

Comment: What JDK version you are using? In Java 7, they introduced alternative syntaxes for integer literals; e.g. 1_000 is the same as 1000. You can refer similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037450/strange-error-in-r-java-even-after-cleaning-the-project-underscores-can-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't the XML file that was the issue. It was an image in the resource folder with a name that didn't follow the standard naming rules and thus made the R.java to generate that error.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some thing error in your res folder once check each and every file and clean your project once and refresh it again..

Sounds like the R.java file has not updated, try some of these general pointers to begin with:

- Do not manually edit any of the files in the `gen` folder, as these are automatically built for you.
- If you find it is out of sync then try refreshing the project.
- If that did not work try a clean (project -> clean)
- If that did not work delete the `gen` folder, from within Eclipse, (do not panic) it will then be rebuilt by Eclipse - however if there is a coding error of some sort it may not do this straight away.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The reason it regenerates same is because it regenerates from your code you should check the .xml files of this project the problem is probably at 1 of them try clearing xmls you have created then regenerate it.

Comment: well from what i experienced the syntax error usually comes from setting the id of an item with numbers. That is why i suggested it.

Edit : Alex can you try this and get back to me ? i cant comment on your question due to my reputation ...

Comment: none of my id have numbers as their naming or have numbers attached with them.